# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'XXX' not found in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have got an error for

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'X2019..YR2019.' not found.

I know there are some posts discussing about this error, while none of them really help me to solve my issue or are in the similar case as mine.

Here is my code. I tried to display the fertility rate on a world map in 2019. The error shows as I run the last code to display the graph.

```
# combine data frame with map
fertility_rate_map <- joinCountryData2Map(fertility_rate, 
                                  joinCode = "ISO3",
                                  nameJoinColumn = "Country.Code")


-----------------
# create cut off points in Population
fertility_rate_map$X2019..YR2019._C <- base::cut(fertility_rate_map$X2019..YR2019.,
                              breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 
                                         4, 5, 6,
                                         7, 8), 
                              labels = 1:8, right = F, ordered_result = T)

-----1-----
# define colors
palette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n=8, name='Oranges'))(8)
palette = c("white", palette)
# create map
world_fertility <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = fertility_rate_map, aes(fill = X2019..YR2019._C)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = palette) +
# customize legend title
labs(fill = "Fertility Rate") +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      # surpress legend
      legend.position = "none")

-----2-----
# create map
world_fertility <- ggplot(data = fertility_rate_map) +  
  ggplot2::geom_sf(data = fertility_rate_map) +  
  aes(fill = X2019..YR2019._C) +  
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma") +  
  ggplot2::coord_sf(xlim = c(-175, 47.5),  
                    ylim = c(23, 85),  
                    expand = FALSE) +  
  labs(title = "World Fertilty Rate",  
       subtitle = "around the world",  
       fill = "Share of Fertility (%)") +  
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(plot.title =  
          element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +  
  theme(plot.subtitle =
          element_text(hjust = 0.5))
----------
# display map
world_fertility
```

Before I create the map, I use the `joinCountryData2Map` to join the fertility_rate and built-in data world by the Country code. Then, I create cut off points in population into 8 breaks, called "X2019..YR2019._C". I tried two different codes to create the map but they all use same packages.

I feel this error is pretty weird, since I have checked whether the variable is in the fertility_rate_map, then it is there! Pretty not sure why the error message said it cannot found it. I guess the error might come from `geom_sf(data = fertility_rate_map, aes(fill = factor(X2019..YR2019._C)))`.
Btw, is it possible that my joined data is a dataframe but not a datatable so this error comes? I think this doesn't really matter but not sure about this.

I am still new to R, hope can receive any helps from here so that I could finish my project :(

[image]

Comment: Please provide the dataset `fertility_rate` or at least an exemplary slice of it by pasting the output of `dput(head(fertility_rate))`.

Comment: Thanks for reminder! I have screenshot part of the dataset. The year column is from 1980 to 2020 and I just use 2019 to test for the plot in my code.

Comment: Hard to say/replicate without example data - as already suggested `dput(head(fertility_rate))` would provide data including the data structure, class, and column types, which will make it easier to solve the issue.  Your ggplot code looks like it should work if your data has the correct format. But I think `joinCountryData2Map` returns an object of class `"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"`, which you likely need to transform so that `geom_sf` can make use of it.